# Suggestions for hybrid factoring algorithm on DWave and Qiskit

Tags: quantum-algorithms, qiskit, shors-algorithm, d-wave

I was wondering if the multi-prime factoring problem can be solved in a hybrid approach using DWave (to factor) and Shor's algorithm (in Qiskit)? Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Prasanth and welcome to the site. Please note that this site is not suitable for opinion-based discussions, which your phrasing seems to be tailored at. Also, can you add more context? Why would you think this is/isn't possible? Where did you get the idea? etc.